# How can I show location information without using MapAnnotation pin?

Tags: iphone, location

I know map annotation and by clicking on that annotation pin I get the information about that particular place but I want to display all that information without that annotation pin so how it is possible Actually I have searchbar on the top and I will give city name and I get the Detail information on that Square box in place of Annotation.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html This is the Best Sample code for such kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [CLLocationManager reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

You can get the user position, then you can do what you want (use reverse geocoding, show in custom map or what you want..)